# Accessing data values in c3js in data events

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, c3.js, c3

I am trying to figure out, if there is a way to access the values from the `Company` data array in the `onclick` event. So far using the `api` functions I only get to the `Users` array.

```
var chartCompany = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#users-chart',        
    data: {
        x: 'Company',
        url: '/ajax_call',
        mimeType: 'json',
        type: 'bar',
        axes: {
            Company: 'x'
        },
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log(chartCompany.data()); }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
             show: false
        },
    }
});
```

And the json response from the server:

```
{
 "Company": ["Company 1", "Company 2", "Company 2"],
 "Users"  : [10, 20, 30]
}
```

Any help/ideas will be highly appreciated.

[Edit 1] To elaborate on my question: When clicking on a data from Users (which is displayed as bars) I would like to get the corresponding Company.

[Edit 2] Working static example: http://jsfiddle.net/et37a9t2/

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but can you put together a fiddle of your chart without the ajax call, just a standalone version?

Comment: I put up a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/et37a9t2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of trying out different things, I finally just looked at the chart object itself and discovered a property `categories`. This is populated, when the x-axis is declared to be of type category as it is in my case. So to get the data from the x-axis one needs to call the `.categories()` function.

```
        ...
        },
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log(chartCompany.categories()[d.index]); }
    },
    ...
```

When clicking on a bar in the chart the corresponding category will be returned.